# Parsing raw text and extracting object mentions and the 'and', 'or' relation between them given a predefined set of objects

Tags: parsing, nlp, text-analysis

I have a predefined list of objects such as

```
["pop", "pizza", "orange juice", "apple juice", "pasta", "taco", ...]
```

I'm given a raw text asking for these objects such as

```
Buy a pizza for me and a pasta for my friend. Also buy me a pop, an orange juice, or an apple juice.
```

I would like to extract the objects mentioned in the text as well as the 'and', 'or' relationship between them. E.g., for the example above, I need the output to be something like:

```
[["pizza"], ["pasta"], ["pop", "orange juice", "apple juice"]]
```

showing the text is asking for pizza, pasta, and at least one object from (pop, orange juice, apple juice). i.e., the text is looking for (pizza AND pasta AND (pop OR orange juice OR apple juice)). There can be several variations in the raw text.

I was looking at parsing and nlp techniques, but could not find anything helpful. I appreciate any help or pointer.

Comment: Have you thought about using [dependency] parse tree?

Comment: Yes, but a parse tree only determines the verbs, nouns, noun phrases, ...
How can I go from a parse tree to the output I need? Specially for a sentence such as "I need at least one of these: pop, apple juice, orange juice."

Answer (score 1):

I would using a combination of verb-SRL and other annotations:

Here is the output annotations for your input sentences: 
[image]

As you can see, the things that you want often appear with "A1" label:

- A1.thing needed: at least one of these: pop, apple juice, orange juice
- A1.thing bought: a pizza
- A1.thing bought: a pop, an orange juice, or an apple juice

And it misses "pasta". Within "A1" span it's often easy to split into different items, say by splitting on commas.

Note that this also tells you who wants it; for example: A0.neader: I

Btw you can play with the demo yourself here: http://deagol.cs.illinois.edu:8080/

If you want to connect "I" to "me", etc, of course you can use co-reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the demo you shared. Since I have a list of all things I'm looking for (e.g., pizza, pop, ...), finding those things in the text is not a problem. The problem is in understanding whether there is an 'AND' or an 'OR' relationship between them. Is there any way I can find this relationship between the items from the verb-SRL tree?